# Merge filecontents and call data from only one file

Tags: filecontents

i have 2 filecontent with different structure: test1.tex and test2.tex.

But i want to call data from only one file (ex:test.tex)

How can i build only one file test.tex that includes data of 2 file test1.tex and test2.tex?

My minimal code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{datatool}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    
    \begin{filecontents*}{test1.tex}
    Acol, Bcol, NoCol
    Ax,Bx,1
    Ay,By,3
    A1,B22,2
    A2,B44,4
    A3,B11,5
    \end{filecontents*}
    
    \begin{filecontents*}{test2.tex}
    \def\Names{{"ABC","XYZ"}}
    \end{filecontents*}
    
    \DTLloaddb{mydata}{test1.tex}
    \input{test2.tex}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\NameNull}{\Names[0]}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \DTLforeach*{mydata}{\A=Acol,\B=Bcol}%
    {%
    
     \NameNull \hspace{2cm } \A \hspace{2cm } \B \\
     %\newpage
    }%
    
    \end{document}
```

i can manual copy all data from test1.tex and test2.tex to one file test.tex.

But please help how i arrange this data?

Ex:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.tex}

Data copy from test1.tex and can call to main.tex

Data copy from test2.tex and can call to main.tex

\end{filecontents*}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that what you want is difficult to understand. The example you gave already uses data from `test1.tex` (which is not a TeX file, rather CSV) and `test2.tex`. What else do you want? Do you want to read two files in CSV format from `test.tex`? If so, I think you have to process them one by one, with two calls to `\DTLforeach*`, each corresponding to a different database (e.g., `\DTLloaddb{mydata1}{test1.tex}` and `\DTLloaddb{mydata2}{test2.tex}`).

Comment: @frougon thank for your reply. I want to only one file: i can manual copy test1&test2 and past to one test.tex. How is structure of test.tex? Thanks

Comment: Still not sure I understand what you mean. As people already told you, if you want to `\input` test1.tex and test2.tex from test.tex, then test1.tex and test2.tex can't have `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`. When LaTeX processes one document, it must see one occurrence of these commands, no more. So, you can have a skeleton document in test.tex with two `\input` commands for test1.tex and test2.tex, but then these two files can't be full compilable documents: they can only be partial. For instance, they can contain macro definitions and you can use the macros in test.tex.

Comment: @frougon can you guide me that solution: using macros to definite test2 and test 1 in test.tex. And then in main.tex can call data from test.tex. Thank very much.

Comment: I would like to, but I don't understand what you want to do, sorry. The description is too vague for me...

Comment: @frougon. thanks. i use one program Java and it can create automation text file. And i must create 2 file in Latex: test 1 (for columns: Acol, Bcol, NoCol...) and test 2 (for array: \def\Names{{"ABC","XYZ"}}) then i copy data 2 times from my program Java to two created files in Latex. I can reduce step if  two test 2 and test 1 embeded in one test.tex file